# How to type a custom React select component using TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'd like to have a `CustomSelect` React component that works with any predefined set of `options` and have TypeScript warn users when an unknown option is used.

Here is my attempt:

```
type Props<Value> = {
  value: Value;
  onChange: (newValue: Value) => void;
  options: readonly string[];
};

function CustomSelect<Value>({
  value,
  onChange,
  options
}: Props<Value>) {
  return (
    <select
      value={value /* See Issue 1 below */}
      onChange={(e) => {
        onChange(e.target.value); // See Issue 2 below
      }}
    >
      {options.map((value) => (
        <option value={value} key={value}>
          {value}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}
```

Usage:

```
const FRUITS = ["apple", "banana", "melon"] as const;

type Fruit = typeof FRUITS[number];


<CustomSelect<Fruit>    {/* See Bonus question below */}
  value={state.fruit}
  onChange={(newFruit) => { ... }}
  options={FRUITS}
/>
```

This has two TypeScript issues:

#### Issue 1

> Type 'Value' is not assignable to type 'string | number | readonly string[] | undefined'.

#### Issue 2

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Value'.

#### Bonus question

Is it absolutely necessary to pass `<Value>` to the `CustomSelect`, or can `CustomSelect` somehow deduct this `Value` from the provided `options`?

[CodeSandbox Playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-wu-nb6ge)

Comment: What's the `Value` type?

Comment: @DaveNewton `Value` is whatever is passed to `CustomSelect`, e.g. `<CustomSelect<Fruit>` above.

Comment: This is an interesting error. Cant figure it out. But as far as the bonus question. If you leave out that generic <Fruit> when you use component TS will infer type of `onChange` and others that you define based on `value`

Comment: If you want to support types `Value` which are not valid to be passed to the DOM, such as objects, then you need to get a bit trickier than the current answers.  You can use the array index as the `value` prop for the HTML `<option/>`.  You'll want some sort of `mapValueToLabel` prop which is optional if the `Value` is a valid label type but required otherwise.  I can def write those typings into an answer but I don't know if I'm overthinking this or thinking the right amount :)

Comment: I know this is not regarding the question but I would like to suggest you to check about compound component pattern. Your Select component is not reusable enough. Compound component pattern is the best suit for the custom `Select` component.  https://kentcdodds.com/blog/compound-components-with-react-hooks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Value can be Anything

`<Value>` is a generic type parameter with no restrictions.  But you pass it as the `value` prop to the `HTMLOptionElement`.  This prop *does* have restrictions.  It must be:

```
string | number | readonly string[] | undefined
```

So you have a few options:

1. You can limit the acceptable types for `Value` using the `extends` keyword such that only valid option value types are allowed

```
<Value extends string | number | readonly string[] | undefined>
<Value extends string | number>
<Value extends JSX.IntrinsicElements['option']['value']>
<Value extends NonNullable<JSX.IntrinsicElements['option']['value']>>
```

2. You can require that if the `Value` type is not assignable to the `<option>` then you must have an additional prop that maps the `Value` to something you can handle.  Technically we can use the array index as the `value` but what we really need is the `label`.
3. You can require that the `options` prop be an array of objects with `label` and `value`.  This is a common approach in third-party libraries.  Both `label` and `value` should be `string | number` but we can accept any additional properties on the option object such as `data`.

#### Mapping Value

This is an example approach to #2 above.

I am stealing from from @oieduardorabelo's answer to use `e.target.selectedIndex` to get the index of the option as `e.target.value` will always be `string`.

Component

```
type Allowed = string | number;

type BaseProps<Value> = {
  value: Value;
  onChange: (newValue: Value) => void;
  options: readonly Value[];
  mapOptionToLabel?: (option: Value) => Allowed;
  mapOptionToValue?: (option: Value) => Allowed;
};

// mappers required only in certain cirumstances
// we could get fancier here and also not require if `Value` has `value`/`label` properties
type Props<Value> = Value extends Allowed
  ? BaseProps<Value>
  : Required<BaseProps<Value>>;


// type guard function checks value and refines type
const isAllowed = (v: any): v is Allowed =>
  typeof v === "string" || typeof v === "number";

function CustomSelect<Value>({
  value,
  onChange,
  options,
  mapOptionToLabel,
  mapOptionToValue
}: Props<Value>) {
  const toLabel = (option: Value): Allowed => {
    if (mapOptionToLabel) {
      return mapOptionToLabel(option);
    }
    // if our props are provided correctly, this should never be false
    return isAllowed(option) ? option : String(option);
  };

  const toValue = (option: Value): Allowed => {
    if (mapOptionToValue) {
      return mapOptionToValue(option);
    }
    return isAllowed(option) ? option : String(option);
  };

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    onChange(options[e.target.selectedIndex]);
  };

  return (
    <select value={toValue(value)} onChange={handleChange}>
      {options.map((value) => (
        <option value={toValue(value)} key={toValue(value)}>
          {toLabel(value)}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}
```

Usage

```
const FRUITS = ["apple", "banana", "melon"] as const;

type Fruit = typeof FRUITS[number];

const SelectFruit = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState<Fruit>(FRUITS[0]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Value: {selected}</div>

      <CustomSelect value={selected} onChange={setSelected} options={FRUITS} />
    </div>
  );
};

const SelectNumber = () => {
  const [n, setN] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Value: {n}</div>

      <CustomSelect value={n} onChange={setN} options={[0, 1, 2, 3, 5]} />
    </div>
  );
};

interface User {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}

const SelectUser = () => {
  const users: User[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "John"
    },
    {
      id: 322,
      name: "Susan"
    },
    {
      id: 57,
      name: "Bill"
    }
  ];

  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(users[0]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Value: {JSON.stringify(user)}</div>

      <CustomSelect
        value={user}
        onChange={setUser}
        options={users}
        // has an error if no mapOptionToLabel is provided!
        // I don't know why the type for user isn't automatic
        mapOptionToLabel={(user: User) => user.name}
        mapOptionToValue={(user: User) => user.id}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-select-component-f6u05?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 1):

the generic type for the HTML `<option>` value is either `string | number | readonly string[]`,

to make the type selection on `onChange` of the `select` to match your generic type, you need to select from the `props.options` based on the selected index **and not pass the value directly**.

If you do pass the value directly, you will get an type error since `e.target.value` is a `string` and doesn't match the type `Value`.

One way to achieve this is like the following:

```
type OptionValue = string | number;

type Props<Value extends OptionValue> = {
  value: Value;
  onChange: (newValue: Value) => void;
  options: readonly Value[];
};

function CustomSelect<Value extends OptionValue>({
  value,
  onChange,
  options,
}: Props<Value>) {
  return (
    <select
      value={value}
      onChange={(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
        const selectedOption = options[event.currentTarget.selectedIndex];
        onChange(selectedOption);
      }}
    >
      {options.map((value) => (
        <option value={value} key={value}>
          {value}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}

function Form() {
  const fruits = ["apple", "banana", "melon"] as const;
  const [fruit, setFruits] = React.useState<typeof fruits[number]>("apple");
  return <CustomSelect value={fruit} onChange={setFruits} options={fruits} />;
}
```

It is heavily based on the walk through:

- https://mariusschulz.com/blog/passing-generics-to-jsx-elements-in-typescript

from the ["TypeScript Evolution" series](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/series/typescript-evolution)

Answer (score 0):

I think below is the best I can do.

Since `e.target.value` is basically `string` type, so i had to convert it through `as`.

```
type Props<Value> = {
  value: Value;
  onChange: (newValue: Value) => void;
  options: readonly string[];
};

export default function CustomSelect<T extends string | number | readonly string[]>({
  value,
  onChange,
  options
}: Props<T>) {
  return (
    <select
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => {
        onChange(e.target.value as T);
      }}
    >
      {options.map((value) => (
        <option value={value} key={value}>
          {value}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}
```